# Creating lines using google maps api with coordinates from database javascript MySQL PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a navigation type application in which I have to draw a line wherein the start and end points are stored in the Database.

The lines start from start point go to a fixed point (given in code) and terminate at end point.

Here, I take the data from database and store it in a matrix ($locations).
the connection is proper and also the data gets stored in the matrix.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM ship WHERE id=".$id);
    $locations = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($locations, $row);
    }
    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

This is to create 2 variables for JavaScript

```
var nrows = <?php echo json_encode($nrows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
var locMatrix = <?php echo json_encode($locations,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
```

I have created another array DrivePath that helps to set coordinates and create lines.

```
for(var i=1; i<=nrows; i++)
        {
          console.log(locMatrix[i][0]);
            DrivePath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][0], locMatrix[i][1]),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(17.8674, 66.543),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][2], locMatrix[i][3]));
        }
```

Here I am facing an error on the line "console.log(locMatrix[i][0]);" stating "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'locMatrix[i]')"

The complete code is here

https://jsfiddle.net/Prashant_mahajan/u5Lz9jqs/

Hope my error will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: What does the rendered javascript for the line beginning `var locMatrix = ...` look like?  An empty array perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably this.  Javascript arrays are zero indexed, so say you have 5 rows in locMatrix, to loop over them, you need to go from locMatrix[0] to locMatrix[4]

You know you have `nrows` rows.  However you're looping from 1 to nrows, when you really need to loop from 0 to nrows-1.

It's probably looping okay from the 2nd row up to the last row, then trying to do another iteration on an additional row, one more than is in locMatrix.

Try

```
for(var i=0; i < nrows-1; i++)
```

Or just

```
for(var i=0; i < locMatrix.length; i++)
```